# Extract last 10 characters from a string of variable length in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have some sentences like below :

```
i have a river  
he is liar
great
hello miss
there was a river in this area
```

Now i want to extract last 10 characters and have this result

```
ve a river
he is liar
great
hello miss
 this area
```

I have tried to achieve the desired result using this

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 10)
```

The above code works fine for the strings of length higher than 9, but fails for `great` How to overcome this problem using fewest line of vb.net code?

Comment: If mystring.Length() > 10 Then

Comment: can you use a min() function of 2 numbers? i.e. min(10, mystring.Length)

Comment: @boethius - Yes it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep last few charaters in listbox VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878946/keep-last-few-charaters-in-listbox-vb-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last 5 characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813505/get-last-5-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cap the substring using Math.Min so that it will grab 10 or as many as it can from the string.

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - Math.Min(10, mystring.Length))
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Strings.Right Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right?view=netframework-4.7.1) will do what you want.

```
Dim ss = {"i have a river", "he is liar", "great", "hello miss", "there was a river in this area"}
For Each s In ss
    Console.WriteLine(Strings.Right(s, 10))
Next
```

Outputs:

```
ve a river
he is liar
great
hello miss
 this area
```

I assume that the missing space at the start of the last string was a transcription error in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the string (which converts it to array of character), take 10 characters from start, then reverse it back and convert to string by joining array.

```
String.Join("", mystring.Reverse().Take(10).Reverse())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(mystring, 10)
```

Another simple but efficient solution i found :

> **mystring.Substring(Math.Max(0, mystring.Length - 10))**